# Invoking an F# library from C#

Tags: c#, f#

I have an F# class library that is consumed by C#.

The F# library has 2 two types and one simple function that I want to invoke from my C# code.

namespace HFNZ.InfectionStatus.ClassLibrary

```
type Result = 
    | Positive
    | Negative

type TestType = 
    | AntiHBc of Option<Result>
    | AntiHBs of Option<Result>
    | HBeAg of Option<Result>
    | HBsAg of Option<Result>
    | HBVDNA of Option<Result>

module Program =

    let getHVBStatus (test1, test2, test3, test4, test5) =
        match test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 with
        | AntiHBc   (Some(Positive)), 
          AntiHBs   (Some(Positive)), 
          HBeAg     (Some(Positive)), 
          HBsAg     (Some(Positive)), 
          HBVDNA    (Some(Positive))  -> "Normal"

        | _ -> "Elevated"
```

This is my C# code:

```
var positive = new FSharpOption<Result>(Result.Positive);
var antiHBc =  TestType.NewAntiHBc(positive);
var AntiHBs = TestType.NewAntiHBs(positive);
var HBeAg = TestType.NewHBeAg(positive);
var HBsAg = TestType.NewHBsAg(positive);
var HBVDNA = TestType.NewHBVDNA(positive);

Program.getHVBStatus(antiHBc, AntiHBs, HBeAg, HBsAg, HBVDNA);
```

The C# code does not compile due to this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'InfectionStatus.ClassLibrary.TestType' to 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<InfectionStatus.ClassLibrary.TestType, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<InfectionStatus.ClassLibrary.TestType, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<InfectionStatus.ClassLibrary.TestType, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<InfectionStatus.ClassLibrary.TestType, System.Tuple<InfectionStatus.ClassLibrary.TestType, InfectionStatus.ClassLibrary.TestType, InfectionStatus.ClassLibrary.TestType, InfectionStatus.ClassLibrary.TestType, InfectionStatus.ClassLibrary.TestType>>>>>'    UnitTestProject1    D:\F#\Code\InfectionStatus.ClassLibrary\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs   21  Active
```

I tried changing the F# function to use tuples instead of currying but still getting a compilation error.

What is the correct way to pass multiple arguments (non-primitive types) from C# to F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your F# function `getHVBStatus`, you are missing commas between the parameters that you want to pattern match agains (on the `match` line). As a result, the F# type inference turns `test1` into a function that takes `test2` and all the other parameters as arguments.

This is quite hard to spot just from the C# compiler error message, but if you hover over `test1` to see the inferred type in F#, you'll immediately see that there's something wrong. Adding commas on the `match` line should fix the problem:

```
let getHVBStatus (test1, test2, test3, test4, test5) =
    match test1, test2, test3, test4, test5 with
    | AntiHBc   (Some(Positive)), 
      AntiHBs   (Some(Positive)), 
      HBeAg     (Some(Positive)), 
      HBsAg     (Some(Positive)), 
      HBVDNA    (Some(Positive))  -> "Normal"
    | _ -> "Elevated"
```